# Image.IO cant read input file - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Hey i am currently trying to read the byte contents of an image into a byte array in java but cant seem to open the image from file. The console is throwing this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This here is the line in question:

```
BufferedImage im =
   ImageIO.read(
      new File(
         getClass().getResource( "/Images/default_pic.png" ).toURI()));
```

My packages look like this:

```
-UI
  -Class //code getting image here
-UI.Images
  -default_pic.png
```

Comment: The easiest way to debug a name resolution problem is to set a breakpoint on your `ImageIO.read()` and try a lot of different paths until `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` returns something non-null. You can just change the code while the debugger is waiting, then select the `getClass().getResource()` method call and right-click "Inspect" to see the value. In general, Java name resolution is unpredictable and unreliable--there are no actual rules to it--so you just have to explore possibilities by trial-and-error until you hit the spot.

Answer (score 2):

The directory `UI` is missing in your path, I suggest:

```
BufferedImage im =
   ImageIO.read(
      getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
         "/UI/Images/default_pic.png" ));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, after trying yours i also got an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! exception

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Images/default_pic.png"))
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. After trying your code i got a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!" exception

Comment: Where is your image located? src/main/resources/Images would be correct, I believe. Also check your image is .png, not .PNG...

Comment: the image is located in src/UI/Images

Comment: Ok, well see Aerospace's answer. I'll upvote it, can u try it?

Comment: Did you try this without the leading "/", like "Images/default_pic.png"?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file uses CMYK coloring (Don't know if this only applies to jpegs). If that's the case then ImageIO can't read it without an extension.

Check http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2011/08/reading-cmyk-jpeg-images-with-java-imageio/